# Powershell: Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, soap

I am using the following powershell script to send xml data stored in a text file (soap.txt) to an endpoint.

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("charset", 'utf-8')
$headers.Add("SOAPAction", 'nms:rtEvent#PushEvent')

Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:8080/nl/jsp/soaprouter.jsp -Method Post -ContentType 'text/xml' -Headers $headers -InFile D:\Scripts\archive\soap.txt
```

Whilst the above method works fine, I wish to use the -Body param instead so that I can enrich the content but I am facing some issues, below is the code.

```
## Set SOAP headers
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("charset", 'utf-8')
$headers.Add("SOAPAction", 'nms:rtEvent#PushEvent')
$url = "http://localhost:8080/nl/jsp/soaprouter.jsp"

$body = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:nms:rtEvent">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
            ...etc etc
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'

Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType 'application/xml'
```

I am getting the following error

[image: powershell error]

I've also tried

```
$body = @"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:nms:rtEvent">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
...rest of code here asd
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"@
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $url -ContentType 'text/xml' -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

And i get that the header must be modified using the appropiate property or method, so I append the content type also to the header but that doesn't work either, I am using powershell 3.0

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the content of what you are passing in the infile?

Comment: @RanadipDutta essentially, the same content defined in $body variable, I've just removed confidential details, a simple xml SOAP

Comment: Fine. Let me go through it then and a create a sample on it.

Comment: @RanadipDutta I've just found out that is the xml indententation, for some reason powershell didn't accept it. I've removed all the spaces and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to remove the XML indentation in the variable, is this issue documented somewhere? or is it a limitation.

```
$body = @"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:nms:rtEvent">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
...rest of code here asd
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"@
```